# Can I send parameters from MvxSplashScreenActivity to MvxViewModel?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm working on my first MvvmCross project and I'm using a Splash Screen to get some user data from sqlite database and start Login or Main View Model depending on there is or no data.
Then I would like to send those data to the MainViewModel. I would like to know if that if possible to make and how to do it.
This is my MvxSplashScreenActivity code:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    async void SimulateStartup()
    {

        Task<Core.Models.TrackrUserData> result = Mvx.Resolve<RepositoryService>().GetUserDataAsync();
        await Task.Delay(2000); 
        Core.Models.TrackrUserData userData = result.Result;
        if(userData != null){
            await GetProjects(userData);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }else{
            await Task.Delay(1000); 
        }
    }

    async Task<bool> GetProjects(Core.Models.TrackrUserData login)
    {
        var apiService = new ApiService();
        var respuesta = await apiService.GetProjects(login.IdUser.ToString(), login.ActiveTeamId.ToString(), login.Jwt);
        await Mvx.Resolve<RepositoryService>().DeleteProjects();
        var projectsSaved = SaveProjects(respuesta);
        return true;
    }

    async Task<bool> SaveProjects(List<ProjectGetResponse> respuesta)
    {
        foreach (var item in respuesta)
        {
            await Mvx.Resolve<RepositoryService>().CreateProject(new Project
            {
                Id = item.Id,
                Name = item.Name
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to perform all the async work at a View level. Business logic and heavy work is not a concern of the View. Think about this: If you were to create an iOS version of the App, you will need to replicate all the code on that platform too...

You can take advantage of the MVVM implementation that MvvmCross offers and do all the operations at a Core level.

In order to do this, you can follow these steps:

1) Create a class that derives from [MvxNavigationServiceAppStart](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxNavigationServiceAppStart.cs).

2) Override [Start](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxNavigationServiceAppStart.cs#L26) method and make sure you navigate to a ViewModel (MainViewModel in your case) before the method ends.

3) Before navigating, you can perform all the operations that you want. But if you were to do async/await you will end up with an `async void Start` method... which isn't really good. So my recommendation here is to store a simple value to make the initial decisions using something like [this plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings/) and load fast.

4) After that you can do all the heavy work on your initial ViewModel (maybe `MainViewModel`?).

**Final hint**: You should consider loading all dependencies using Dependency Injection in constructors instead of resolving them through the IoC Container.